Not finding main.c file
while flashing a STM nucleo board,after every step and intialising all the ports and saved the file even thought, i couldn't find the main.c file, its not showing in any of the desk
im expecting to find that main.c file and do the programming

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
